# is this a mistake or not in this tutorial?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, stochastic-programming

Please consider

https://stoprog.org/what-stochastic-programming

and look at  "A SIMPLE INTEGER RECOURSE MODEL" at

"Stochastic Integer Programming" section.

Should not $b_i$ be $y_ib_i$ in the cost function and $q_i$ in the second-stage function as in the attached picture?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain all the necessary information.  Providing the reference link is fine, but if that link were to rot, then this question would not be useful for **future visitors**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in the text are the same as $a$, $b$ and $g$ in the model, then $b_i$ should be $b_i y_i$.

Comment: In addition, there should be  $q_i$ in the second-stage cost  function as in the attached picture, right?